# Using 'it' at the end of a sentence

Tags: style

Is it okay, if we don't use **it** at the end? Just curious.

> This book is the perfect companion for those who need inspiration in a
>   quick read and have fun while reading **[it]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and have fun while reading.

uses "fun while reading" in a general sense (you have fun/enjoy reading in general), not only "This book".

> ...and have fun while reading **it**.

is specific about "fun while reading" this book. Regarding other books we have no idea.

Comment: Wow. That's a great explanation. Appreciate. I'm going with **it**. Thank you.

Comment: You never know when you might want someone to be miserable reading some other book, after all.

Comment: @CrazyEyes But some people (like me) have a difficult time reading. Unless it is something of specific interest, reading is not fun, at all.

Comment: @user3169 Most people don't like reading things they have no interest in. I was just joking, pointing out the silly idea that you might want someone to enjoy one book, but not any others.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case? Yeah, that's totally fine grammatically. Personally, I even think that it sounds a bit better. It's worth noting that in some situations, it *is* needed:

> "I like **[it]**!"
>
> "Don't hit the [infinite probability drive](http://cdn-static.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeek/files/styles/insert_main_wide_image/public/hitch-01.jpg?itok=HR-qSucM), you'll break **[it]**!"
>
> "A lad's night out? I don't think we're up for **[it]**."

Comment: Thank you @HarryCBurn for the helpful explanation. Yeah, **it** sounds a bit better. I felt the same and was curious.